# Use SOMotionDetector with swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use SOMotionDetector in a swift project

Is there a way to translate that objective c method into swift?

```
- (void)motionDetector:(SOMotionDetector *)motionDetector locationChanged:(CLLocation *)location
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Converting delegate methods to Swift is not exactly the same as other Obj-C methods, as the explicit parameter names are important. In this example, you would want `func motionDetector(motionDetector:SOMotionDetector locationChanged location:CLLocation)`.

Comment: No problem, submitted an answer for better explanation of why this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Converting delegate methods from Obj-C to Swift is similar to creating standard Swift functions, with one extra rule: **explicit parameter names**.

In your example it would be like so:

```
func motionDetector(motionDetector:SOMotionDetector locationChanged location:CLLocation)
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

Why do we have this `locationChanged` in front of the second argument definition of `location:CLLocation`?

It's so your selector signature remains `motionDetector:locationChanged:` while allowing your method parameter name to be `location`.

Let's consider the following `NSURLConnection` delegate in Obj-C:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

If we convert it to Swift without the explicit parameter names, you'll see why this is awkward:

```
func connection(connection:NSURLConnection didReceiveData:NSData)
{
    self.mutableData.appendData(didReceiveData);  // weird local variable name...
}
```

Now we move `didReceiveData` as the parameter name but change the local variable name to `data` instead for clarity:

```
func connection(connection:NSURLConnection didReceiveData data:NSData)
{
    self.mutableData.appendData(data);  // Ahhh.. much better!
}
```

So as you can see, it's very similar to standard Swift functions but just requires the parameter names. Note that you can do this for non-delegate functions if you'd like!